# Media player control works only in IE (not FF/Chrome)

Tags: c#, css

I have media player control in my web page which that I able to get the media player only in Internet Explorer I can't able get in any other browser like Chrome or Firefox and code is **media.aspx.cs:**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="_Default" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="Media-Player-ASP.NET-Control" Namespace="Media_Player_ASP.NET_Control"
TagPrefix="cc1" %>
  <cc1:media_player_control id="Media_Player_Control1" runat="server" 
       Height="314px" Width="518px" 
       style="z-index: 100; left: 4px; position: absolute; top: 9px">
    </cc1:media_player_control>
```

Comment: <cc1:media_player_control id="Media_Player_Control1" runat="server" Height="314px" Width="518px" style="z-index: 100; left: 4px; position: absolute; top: 9px">

Comment: What kind of error are you getting on Chrome or Firefox?

Answer (score 0):

Normally ActiveX controls work only in IE, so as Media Player is an ActiveX control it does not work by default in other browsers.

For Firefox you may check out [Using the Windows Media Player Control with Firefox](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd564583%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)